# Parsing GenBank file: get locus tag vs product

Tags: python, perl, parsing, bioperl, genbank

Basically, a GenBank file consists on gene entries (announced by 'gene' followed by its corresponding 'CDS' entry (only one per gene) like the two I show here below. I would like to get locus_tag vs product in a tab-delimited two column file. 'gene' and 'CDS' are always preceded and followed by spaces.

[A previous question suggested a script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888945/parsing-genbank-file)

The problem is that it seems that because 'product' has sometimes '/' character inside its name, its having conflicts with this script, that, as far as I can understand, is using '/' as field separator to store information in an array?

I would like to solve this, either modifying this script or building other one.

```
perl -nE'
  BEGIN{ ($/, $") = ("CDS", "\t") }
  say "@r[0,1]" if @r= m!/(?:locus_tag|product)="(.+?)"!g and @r>1
' file


 gene            complement(8972..9094)
                 /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
 CDS             complement(8972..9094)
                 /locus_tag="HAPS_0004"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="hypothetical protein"
                 /protein_id="YP_002474657.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:219870282"
                 /db_xref="GeneID:7278619"
                 /translation="MYYKALAHFLPTLSTMQNILSKSPLSLDFRLLFLAFIDKR"
 gene            68..637
                 /locus_tag="HPNK_00040"
 CDS             68..637
                 /locus_tag="HPNK_00040"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="NinG recombination protein/bacteriophage lambda
                 NinG family protein"
                 /protein_id="CRESA:HPNK_00040"
                 /translation="MIKPKVKKRKCKCCGGEFKSADSFRKWCSAECGVKLAKIAQEKA
                 RQKAIEKRNREERAKIKATRERLKSRSEWLKDAQAIFNEYIRLRDKDEPCISCRRFHQ
                 GQYHAGHYRTVKAMPELRFNEDNVHKQCSACNNHLSGNITEYRINLVRKIGAERVEAL
                 ESYHPPVKWSVEDCKEIIKTYRAKIKELK"
```

Comment: You understand wrong. The only issue with `/` is here that it clashes with the default delimiter of the match operator `m//`, but that has already been handled by replacing the delimiter with `!`, as in `m!!`. It has nothing to do with arrays or field separators.

Comment: This format (GenBank) seems to be some kind of standard format, so I bet there is a module that will parse it for you, which will most likely be simpler and more secure than this sort of quick fix that you are attempting here.

Comment: Here's one: [`Bio::GenBankParser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bio%3A%3AGenBankParser), for example.

Comment: Bio::GenBankParser just parses GenBank records into YAML format, same problem, as least for me.

Comment: No, that is not true. I don't know where you got that from, it certainly is not mentioned in the documentation that it parses GenBank into YAML. However, in another search result, `genbank-parser.pl`, it says `parse GenBank records into YAML`. Perhaps you confused the two search results? As far as I can tell, this will parse the GenBank entry into a hash reference, e.g. `print $rec->{'ACCESSION'};`

Comment: Is this normal that the second `product` has a newline in its value?

Comment: Yes, there's a new line there, leeduhem

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Perl seems to be helpful for some people that have ludicrous amounts of capital letters in their questions. And it apparently does allow some shenanigans with something called a genbank format.

Comment: @popnard I've added a simple Perl script that parses a GenBank file and prints out the records you were after. Looks to be the same output as your broken one-liner would print if fixed, but extracted in a safer and simpler way. And its not YAML either.

Comment: If you want to parse GenBank files (which are a "standard" format for sequence data) using Perl, you should indeed be using BioPerl, specifically Bio::SeqIO. See this HOWTO - http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO:SeqIO and the related Feature Annotation HOWTO - http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO:Feature-Annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your sample GenBank file was incomplete, I went online to find a sample file that could be used in an example, and I found [this file](http://www.nmpdr.org/FIG/wiki/view.cgi/FIG/GBK).

Using this code and the [`Bio::GenBankParser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bio::GenBankParser) module, it was parsed guessing what parts of the structure you were after. In this case, "features" that contained both a `locus_tag` field and a `product` field.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Bio::GenBankParser;

my $file = shift;
my $parser = Bio::GenBankParser->new( file => $file );
while ( my $seq = $parser->next_seq ) {
    my $feat = $seq->{'FEATURES'};
    for my $f (@$feat) {
        my $tag = $f->{'feature'}{'locus_tag'};
        my $prod = $f->{'feature'}{'product'};
        if (defined $tag and defined $prod) {
            say join "\t", $tag, $prod;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
perl script.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

**Output:**

```
MG_001  DNA polymerase III, beta subunit
MG_470  CobQ/CobB/MinD/ParA nucleotide binding domain-containing protein
```

The output from your one-liner for the same input would be:

```
MG_001  DNA polymerase III, beta subunit
MG_470  CobQ/CobB/MinD/ParA nucleotide binding
                     domain-containing protein
```

Assuming of course that you add the `/s` modifier to the regex to account for multiline entries (which [leeduhem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004301/leeduhem) pointed out in the comments):

```
m!/(?:locus_tag|product)="(.+?)"!sg
#                                ^---- this
```

Comment: Module is installed, but I have this error message: 'syntax error at /Users/bernardo/Documents/BioLinux/A0_scripts/parse_gbk_2.pl line 13, near "say join"
Execution of /Users/bernardo/Documents/BioLinux/A0_scripts/parse_gbk_2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.'

Comment: Oh right, you need `use feature 'say'` to use `say()`.

Comment: @popnard It's always nicer to use a module. Most of this code was taken from the documentation for the module, besides the printing.

Comment: OK, worked for one file but failed for the others: '       ERROR (line 5): Invalid section: Was expecting commented line, or
               header, or locus, or dbsource, or definition, or
               accession line, or project line, or version line, or
               keywords, or source line, or organism, or reference, or
               features, or base count, or contig, or origin, or
               comment, or record delimiter

       ERROR (line 5): Invalid startrule: Was expecting eofile but found
               "DBLINK Project: 59273" instead'

Comment: File not working is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-ZAuZe8jldcTNZUzdXd0lCREU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This one worked, it seems is line 5 where the script is expecting something that there is not there. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-ZAuZe8jldVV9ObHV6NnBMOWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Deleted the problematic line and seems to be working well: DBLINK      Project: 59273
            BioProject: PRJNA59273

Comment: I don't really know anything about the format, so can't say anything about that. But it seems as though your files may be corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Having read your duplicated question http://www.biostars.org/p/94164/ (please don't double post like this), here's a minimal Biopython answer:

```
import sys
from Bio import SeqIO
filename = sys.argv[1] # Takes first command line argument input filename
for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "genbank"):
    for feature in record.features:
        if feature.type == "CDS":
            locus_tag = feature.qualifiers.get("locus_tag", ["???"])[0]
            product = feature.qualifiers.get("product", ["???"])[0]
            print("%s\t%s" % (locus_tag, product))
```

With minor changes you can write this out to a file instead.